# evaluate two bools for a single bool result

Tags: c#, asp.net, boolean, repeater, databinder

I have a asp repeater and one of the items requires me to show or hide a text string depending upon the state of TWO boolean values

This works fine:

```
<asp:Label ID="X" runat="server" Text="yadayada" Visible='<%# (bool)DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "field1") %>'>
```

Unfortunately I need to compare two fields. I'm trying to for the logic as follows:

```
True + True = True
True + False = False
False + True = False
```

So I try this:

```
'<%# (bool)DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "field1") + (bool)DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "field1") %>' >
```

I also tried placing an `"if"` statement before the logic to do a typical `c#` or `(||)` evaluation but the compiler won't allow the `"if"`

Any help would be greatly apprecieated.

Comment: Use `&&` instead of `+`

Comment: Looks like you want AND: both true is true, anything else is false. try `&&` instead of `||` or `+`.

Comment: the && worked. Thanks all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `&&` operator instead of `+`. Try using this:

```
Visible='<%# (bool)Eval("field1") && (bool)Eval("field1") %>'
```

Comment: Well, `&&` will give you `true` if both of the operands are evaluated `true`. Isn't it what you want? Do you want `true` if both operands are `false`?

Comment: Your suggested answer seems to be working great mshsayem. Thanks.